# Mobile Browser Tap Event

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, zepto

I am working on a mobile HTML 5 prototype, and I recently added some animations to my app. I am using Zepto and I am really happy with it. However whenever I tap something in the app, there is a very quick blinking effect, as a result of this blinking the animation doesnt look very smooth. I know I couldn't do a very good job explaining the problem but maybe this video would make it more clear:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2kf1l0uhos2fson/IMG_0883.MOV

Basically I am trying to get rid of this blinking.

edit: I am using Backbone Marionette with Zepto and wrote my own slideToggle function

```
var EmailView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    events:{

            "tap .meal-info" : "editModelTouch",
            "click .meal-info" : "editModel",

    },

    template: _.template(emailTemplate),

    initialize : function(){
        console.log(window.mobilecheck);
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.model.on('change', this.render);
    },

    editModel : function(e){
        if(window.mobilecheck) return
        $("#" + this.model.id).slideToggle();
    },

    editModelTouch : function(e){
        $("#" + this.model.id).slideToggle();

    },

});
```

using this for slideToggle: https://github.com/Ilycite/zepto-slide-transition/blob/master/zepto-slide-transition.js

Comment: Are you repainting the whole page in any way? I recommend that you use JavaScript for changing part of the interface after the html is loaded.

Comment: yea I am using javascript.. putting up some code now..

Comment: First of all, try debugging the code by putting some alerts in and checking if any function is unwantedly called. I am thinking of editModel and editModelTouch unnamed functions both being called in the tap event. Please ensure that both events are triggered separately and that tap is not considered as click event too and does not trigger any click function.

Comment: yes both events are getting called but if its a mobile phone the click event just doesnt do anything because of the line if(window.mobilecheck) return, also when I just put the tap event the and delete the other blinking continues

Comment: Ok. Check out the line "this.model.on('change', this.render);" If
"$("#" + this.model.id).slideToggle();" explicitly re-renders  the page, you are going to have a double rendering, right? (As rendering callback will be triggered in every page change I guess).
I apologize for assuming and not directly answering, as I am not familiar with Zepto. Trying to help via logic assumations.

Comment: "$("#" + this.model.id).slideToggle();"  doesnt change the model